# Pass data between androidx fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am simply trying to pass results from one fragment to another.

Following [Android's example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between) exactly to set up the receiving fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String key, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
            // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
            String result = bundle.getString("bundleKey");
            // Do something with the result...
        }
    });
}
```

for some reason android studio can't find `setFragmentResultListener()`. Taking a peek into the `FragmentManager` class, it looks like the method is missing? or is hidden...

Im using `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.9`

Any guidance/insight is GREATLY appreciated

Comment: please post your gradle file as well

Answer (score 1):

solved, needed to add `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha04'` (or higher, i think the most recent is *-alpha07) to my build.gradle